# SSIS Package (SQL 2016) getting failed from batch execution

Tags: batch-file, ssis, permissions, sharepoint-2013

We have developed SSIS package which had target framework SQL Server 2014. 
Package has 2 states:

```
1. Which truncates the required SQL Table.
2. Pull data from SharePoint list data by hitting Service call and dumps data to truncated sql server table.
```

Latter on some SQL Server 2016 upgrades been done on server from IT department. So Dev team has to change target version in SSIS to SQL Server 2016. Which is working fine from SSDT tool (All states executes perfect).

The generated "`.dtsx`" I found in "~/obj/Development" path in source code directory. Then we developed the the `batch` file which is targeting to execute generated .`dtsx` file. If we executes the batch file `as administrator` it doesn't works, takes amount of time and shows `"Operation TimeOut"` at the end. Why should this is happening, any clue ?

Comment: maybe try to run it through SQL job agent to get some error messages or detailed view on where it fails and so on. It could be many reasons. Furthermore, since you had developed on SQL 2014 before, some queries might need to be looked upon. I just myself migrated to SQL 2016, and i had to change som view queries and persist some tables because they were broken. I had some views on 2014 which only took seconds but on 2016 they took serveral hours and never finished (hence your timeouts)

Comment: As limitation there is no SQL Job Agent on server. But will check for sure.  secondly, No SP has called during the SharePoint SVC call. Hence Possibly it is something that unable to fetch or establish bridge between package and Sharepoint under some critical privileges. Still mybad, unable to find out the way .

Comment: Any updates on this, still struggling to fix it.

Comment: You really need to provide more info. What does it execute? What does the SQL look like and so on.

Comment: As mentioned, job has 2 states. At 1st, it truncates the SQL table in which I want to insert the records. In Second state, Pull request from SharePoint List and dump data to truncated table. One thing I forgot to mention, this is running in VPN with LDAP authentication. Where as SharePoint List containing site has permission to NT Authority user group.